# Some shepherds came up, bringing with them a man

Tags: modifiers

> While the dispute was going on, some shepherds came up, bringing with
>   them a man whose hands were bound behind his back.

Source: New York State Testing Program: ELA Common Core Sample Questions

Is *bringing* an adjectival participle phrase that modifies *shepherds*? If not, what does it modify, or what is it anyway?

**Edit:**
Related: Parts of Speech of: [come+ verbing](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/105729/parts-of-speech-of-come-verbing)

Answer (score 4):

The participle phrase headed by **bringing** can be understood to modify the previous *clause* **some shepherds came up**. We need not think that it must attach to a single word in that clause, whether that be **shepherds** or the verb-phrase **came up**.  The participle phrase expresses an action collateral with or incidental to the action expressed in the clause it modifies or pertains to.

Here, the primary action is {some shepherds came up} and the collateral action is {bringing with them a man who ...his back}